# Why isn't promise a data type in Scheme?

Tags: scheme, lazy-evaluation

The object returned by `delay` in Scheme is "a promise", but promises are not considered to be a type (so there is no `promise?` procedure, and it's not listed as a type in R5RS or R6RS).

Is there a strong reson why this is so? It would seem quite natural to me to do something like `(if (promise? x) (force x) x)`, for example. (And I see that some implementations will let me force non-promises, and others will not). Also, if I can store something in a variale and pass it around, I feel like it *should* have a type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There can't be that strong a reason, since [MIT/GNU scheme](http://www.gnu.org/software/mit-scheme/documentation/mit-scheme-ref/Promises.html), defines a `promise?` function.

Answer (score 4):

I think it allows for a more optimized implementation of `delay/force`. The fact that the forced value can be memoized (so that a promise is really forced only once and the resulting value is returned on subsequent `force` calls) blurs the distinction between a promise and its resulting value. If you have `promise?` you cannot substitute a forced promise by its value everywhere it is needed. Therefore, depending on the implementation, a promise can be indistinguishable from any other Scheme value.

Comment: That makes sense! Thanks for answering. (I still think there _could_ be a promise? predicate that would answer #t whenever you can use force on the object -- even if it always returns true.)

Comment: Wait, what does memoization have to do with the types (force x) and x?  Force will always return a value, and x is always a promise, unless I am misunderstanding this.